# Chaining async redux actions without duplicating calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the need to make many calls to an api. Those calls require an input value that is acquired from a separate call. I want to have a setup where I can call an async action (to make an api call, then update state with the returned data) that is able to identify if the state already has the input value necessary to make the call, and if not, make that call first.

I am currently able to do so, when making a single api. It does also work with multiple, but thats where the issues arises. When observing the action calls in dev tools using the redux addon, you can see that the action/api call for meta data is called multiple times.

My goal is that if one or many api calls are made before the meta data exists (the xid in my example) then one singular call would occur, then the batch of previously existing async actions/apis would occur.

In one slice I have two asynxThunks

```
    const fetchMockDataDependent = createAsyncThunk(
    'donk/fetchMockData',
    async (inputs, thunkAPI) => {
      //if state doesnt have the xid, then we instead need to dispatch that action, then this one again. Or something like that
      let xid = thunkAPI.getState().metaData.xid;
      if (!xid) {
        xid = await thunkAPI.dispatch(fetchMockMetaData()).unwrap();
      }
      const response = await fetch(`/api/fakeDataSuccess?xid=${xid}`);
      const parsedResponse = await response.json();
      return parsedResponse;
    }
  );

  const fetchMockDataDependentDuplicate = createAsyncThunk(
    'donk/fetchMockDataDuplicate',
    async (inputs, thunkAPI) => {
      //if state doesnt have the xid, then we instead need to dispatch that action, then this one again. Or something like that
      let xid = thunkAPI.getState().metaData.xid;
      if (!xid) {
        xid = await thunkAPI.dispatch(fetchMockMetaData()).unwrap();
      }
      const response = await fetch(`/api/fakeDataSuccess?xid=${xid}`);
      const parsedResponse = await response.json();
      return parsedResponse;
    }
  );
```

And in another slice I have one async Thunk that would get the meta data (xid)

```
const fetchMockMetaData = createAsyncThunk(
  'metaData/fetchMockData',
  async (inputs) => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/fakeMetaData');
    const parsedResponse = await response.json();
    return parsedResponse;
  }
);
```

in the html I dispatch like so

```
<button onClick={() => {
          dispatch(fetchMockDataDependent())
          dispatch(fetchMockDataDependentDuplicate())
        }}>fetch api data thunk</button>
```

[image: redux dev tools]

Comment: Maybe make the the `onClick` handler async and await the first dispatch?

Comment: I suppose I can try that but I have a concern when I scale this and implement it in the project with my company. If each potential component triggers its own API call through it's specific async thunk action, while implementing logic to determine if it needs to make a preceding call, might still end up making duplicate calls. This is due to my lack of understanding with how redux toolkit batches calls as well as what all the options are for async chaining. I don't want to assume that all the preliminary calls need to be made because that could result in unnecessary API calls as well